# How can I use leaflet-polylinedecorator with a vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I have a Vue 2 sample project at https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test

This is a simple import issue for my [code](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/src/components/LeafletTest.vue) that I am not sure how to handle.

A couple of things I have tried are to modify the [code](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/src/components/LeafletTest.vue) to do:

```
<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";
import * from 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
```

but this results in a build error:

```
  10:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "as"
> 4 | import * from 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
```

To the [index.html](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/public/index.html), I also tried adding:

```
<script src="../node_modules/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js"></script>
```

but that results in the runtime error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:1:1)
```

What needs to be changed so I can import and use this leaflet extension with a vue app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found was to modify [main.js](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/src/main.js) so it looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

require( "../node_modules/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js" );

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Adding the `require` resolved the problem.

I would be interested in alternative solutions, if there are any.